# Changing from a textbox onblur to onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

I have the following code on my partial view:

```
    @foreach (var lineItem in Model.LineItems)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ImageBlocks", new { imageID = lineItem.Product.SelfOrDefault().Image.SelfOrDefault().ImageId, Width = 75 })" alt="Thumbnail" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span title="@(lineItem.Description ?? "")" id="lineItemDescription">@(lineItem.Product.ReceiptName ?? "")</span><br />
            <span id="lineItemSKU">@lineItem.Product.SKU</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>@((lineItem.Product.InventorySummary ?? 0).ToString())</span><br />
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="lineItemQuantity" name="lineItemQuantity" value="@lineItem.Quantity" onblur="changeCartQty(@lineItem.Product.SKU,this.value)" /></td>
        @if (lineItem.Discount != null ? lineItem.Discount.DiscountCategory != DiscountCategory.ORDER : true)
        {
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="lineItemAmount" name="lineItemAmount" value="@lineItem.AdjustedUnitPrice.Value.ToString("C")" /><br />(Adj. @(lineItem.DiscountDisplayValue))
            </td>
            <td>@lineItem.AdjustedTotalLinePrice.Value.ToString("C")</td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td>@lineItem.BaseUnitPrice.Value.ToString("C")</td>
            <td>@lineItem.TotalLineBaseValue.ToString("C")</td>
        }
        <td><a href="#" class="removeItem" value="@lineItem.Product.SelfOrDefault().SKU">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
}
<script>
```

On the lineItemQuantity text input, I want to change this from onblur to an onKeyDown event to capture the "Enter" key pressed to call the changeCartQty function with the same parameters.  Here is the function being called:

```
function changeCartQty(ProductId, Quantity) {
var userId = $('#ID').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/Orders/AddtoCart",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    datatype: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: { "ProductID": ProductId, "Quantity": Quantity, "UserID": userId},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Adjusted Quantity in cart");
        success(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error("[Error in Ajax request, adjust price] Code:" + jqXHR.status + "Error: " + errorThrown + " \nText Status: " + jqXHR.resonseText);
    }
})
```

};

This works fine and the amounts update, I just need to change this to an onChange and I am unsure how this would be done.

Thanks.

Comment: seems like a simple event name change ...did you try it?

Comment: I did and it worked.  Thanks.